# Why can't I/ How can I move a project's source control location before it's checked-in?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In TFS, I add a VS project (which adds the project into source control whether I want it to or not).  I realise I've made a mistake with its location, so I want to move the source control folder to the correct location.

However, the TFS option to 'move' is greyed-out until the project is checked-in.  Is TFS forcing me to check it in, and if so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Move command is used for existing files/folders already checked into the TFS.

you have 2 options:

1. Backup your project, undo add, move your project into the correct
   location and add it again
2. Check in your project into the wrong location and move it to the correct location after check-in

Comment: Thanks, I had that as a work-around, but it seems like another irritating niggle with TFS.

Comment: I created a new solution and added it to the wrong team project within a collection. I checked in all changes and I am trying to move the solution to a different team project but Move is disabled.

Comment: You cannot move files between different team projects. Move is working only inside team project

Comment: You will loose history like this if you add it again, no?
Only the second option saves the history as well..